# Upload file from form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form:

`<input type="file" name="CAR_Logo">`
`<button data-action="save" data-name="Africa">Save</>`

How I can update my code to be able to upload the file ?

This is what I have tried:

`$('[data-action="save"]').click(function(e) {`
    `e.preventDefault();`
    `CAR_Name = $(this).data('name');`
    `CAR_Logo = $(this).val('CAR_Logo');`
`});`

Comment: `$(this).val('CAR_Logo');` Why are you assigning the string `"CAR_Logo"` as the button value?

Comment: [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166221/794749)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX

Your form

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="CAR_Logo">
```

Your script

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fd = new FormData(this);
    fd.append('myfile', $('#file').files[0]);
    
$.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to upload a file, you first need a web-based programming language that will run in the background. Javascript/Jquery codes are interpreted by users' computers. What you need is a web server software and related software. For example, it can be php or python django, python flask or ruby on rails.